# Why does oogenesis have to begin in foetal stage itself?

Tags: reproduction, human-physiology, sexual-reproduction

In males, spermatogenesis begins after puberty and they retain this ability throughout their life time. However, in females, oogenesis begins and ends in the foetal stage itself and the female is unable to generate any more oocytes in her lifetime. Is there any reason for this assymetry in nature?

Comment: For ref: [This](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004Natur.428..145J/abstract) and [this](https://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674(05)00650-1?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0092867405006501%3Fshowall%3Dtrue).

Comment: Welcome Muralidhar. This is not simply a Q&A site, here we are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on, see our section on [how to ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).